# SDK Вконтакте Android. Нужно VKAccessToken перевести в String строку

Tags: java, строки, вконтакте, запрос, android-vksdk

Хочу отправлять запросы в Вконтакте, но мне  нужно как то перевести объект VKAccessToken в текстовую строку. То есть что бы сам ключ был в виде строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [исходникам](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/2e628db9fd7487116df84a9fbadaedda3379706f/vk-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/vk/api/sdk/auth/VKAccessToken.kt) - сам токен - это просто свойство объекта VKAccessToken. Засим получить его просто:

```
String token = vKAccessTokenInstanceFromSomeCallback.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: странно что не могла через гугл это найти( Спасибо за оперативную помощь!

Comment: VK в основном на пространстве бывшего СССР используется, засим в поисковиках американских о нём не очень много информации)